# PHP + jQuery getJson returns "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am attempting to access a JSON object from a PHP script that looks like:

```
$results = array(
    'total' => $all_totalf,
    'error' => $all_errorsf,
 );
echo json_encode($results);
```

The JSON object looks like:

```
{"total":"11,644","error":"179"}
```

Then I have a jQuery script that looks like:

```
var url = "get_control_data.php";
var total;
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
var total = data.total;
});
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
```

I am stuck because total is being returned as "undefined". Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on this line in the getJSON callback:

```
var total = data.total;
```

The `var` here declares a new variable named `total` which is scoped only to the callback function. Remove the `var` and your code will set the `total` var in the outer scope instead.

That will only partly solve your problem. The other problem is that the outer code executes synchronously, whilst the callback code will execute asynchronously, sometime after the outer code has finished. This means that this line:

```
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
```

Is run before the total value has been read from the URL. Probably the easiest thing to do is just move that code into the callback, i.e.:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = data.total;
});
```

Comment: No. This question is a duplicate of what I commented.

Comment: Perhaps it is - you hadn't marked the duplicate when I answered - but it's also the reason why his total was undefined.

Comment: @JulianGoacher it is still coming back as undefined. Even when removing the var like:

Comment: var url = "get_control_data.php";
var total;
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
 total = data.total;
});
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;

Comment: @ThomasC, please read the question linked above your's question to solve this problem.

Comment: @JulianGoacher, kindly remove your answer or fix it. That's also good.

Comment: @ThomasC I've updated the answer

Comment: @AdamAzad I've updated the answer to also include a description of how the code is executing, sync vs async. I think because it explicitly explains both scoping and the async behaviour that's it worth keeping.